# Getting Twitter follower and Facebook Likes

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, api, twitter

I'm about to launch a new site and want to show my facebook page likes and twitter follower with little icons on it.

What are the easiest ways to obtain the numbers (follower/likes) with javascript/jQuery?

I want to use only HTML5/CSS3 and jQuery on that Page.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for the twitter followers count.

http://api.syberplanet.net/twitter/

You can use jQuery then to get fetch the results and display them accordingly

Answer (score 3):

Check out the twitter "follow button" api for  the twitter portion

http://dev.twitter.com/pages/follow_button

and the "like button" api for the facebook half

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/